# C# Dictionary within a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am attempting to make my system a bit more dynamic in terms of calling and setting bitmaps for characters; I wanted there to be a massive Dictionary which had all the characters which searches by using two Strings, which are the parameters, to recall or return a bitmap list which is meant to be the value.

```
public Dictionary< Dictionary<String, String>, List<Bitmap>> Character_Spreadsheet = 
  new Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, List<Bitmap> >();

private List<Bitmap> loadAssets(String character, String icon_state) {
  return Character_Spreadsheet[new Dictionary<character, icon_state>];
}
```

But, I receive an error that two parameters are being used like types.

Comment: `<character, icon_state>`. You used them where types are expected. The error is telling you the exact problem.

Comment: Unclear what the error is, but that won't ever work, anyhow.  Do something else.

Comment: I guess that u don't need a Dictionary<string,string> as Key, try to use for example Tuple<string,string> instead

Comment: Since `Dictionary` is a reference type that does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to have "value" equality it makes a very poor key.  Either use `Tuple` like @yolosora suggests or even `Dicitonary<string,Dictionary<string, List<Bitmap>>>` would make more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<character, icon_state>` is invalid you have to define the types instead of variables.

```
private List<Bitmap> loadAssets(String character, String icon_state)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    result.Add(character, icon_state);
    return Character_Spreadsheet[result];
}
```

or inline

```
private List<Bitmap> loadAssets(String character, String icon_state)
{
    return Character_Spreadsheet[new Dictionary<string, string>(){{character, icon_state}}];
}
```

Comment: You've got to mention that using a `Dictionary` as the key to another `Dictionary` is a bad idea and doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I will not speak to whether your code will work or not but the error is because you cannot do this (shown with arrows):

```
return Character_Spreadsheet[new Dictionary<character, icon_state>];
                                              /\            /\
```

You have to provide a type when creating a dictionary, so it would be like this:

```
return Character_Spreadsheet
   [new Dictionary<string, string> { { character, icon_state } }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for commenting and sharing your knowledge with me; I apologies for the  rookie-mistakes because, I just started programming in C# a few days ago and I'm just trying to work my way around it. I took bits from everyone's comments and made what seemed logical and looked better.

```
public Dictionary< Tuple<String,String> , List<Bitmap>> Character_Spreadsheet = new Dictionary<Tuple<String,String> , List<Bitmap> >();

 private List<Bitmap> loadAssets(String character, String icon_state) {
        Tuple<String, String> result = new Tuple<String, String>(character, icon_state);
        return Character_Spreadsheet[result];
    }
```

I hope this look fine and makes sense; please do inform me if not.

Comment: you can write the method in a single line 

`return Character_Spreadsheet[new Tuple<String, String>(character, icon_state)];`

Comment: I wrote it in a separate lines in case, I want to make modifications which I assume so because I'm going to have to switch from Graphics/Bitmap to openGL and I don't know what changes follow along with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something akin to

```
private Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, IEnumerable<System.Drawing.Bitmap>> _assets;

public IEnumerable<Bitmap> loadAssets(string character, string iconState)
{
    return _assets[new Tuple<string, string>(character, iconState)];
}
```